# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token when sending parameter

Tags: javascript, ajax

I would like to show my ship_reg_num from database in ajax response, I using bottom to sending my field and i will show the ship_reg_num to other function, and I debug the code is `show_name(2d1c9a7158625608);`this is my code :

```
<script>
            function show_new_chat(){
                var param_obj = {action: 'voyage/find_all_ship_voyage'}
                var qs = decodeURIComponent($.param(param_obj));
                $.ajax({

                    type: "get",
                    url: 'transport/',
                    data: $(this).serialize() + '&' + qs,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(res)
                    {
                        var str = '<div>';
                        if (res.data != 0) {
                            $.each(res.data, function(k, v) {
                                str += '<ul>';
                                str += '<button type="button" onclick="show_name('+v.ship_reg_num+');" id="'+v.ship_reg_num+'" style="text-decoration: none; background-color: transparent;" >'+v.ship_name+'</button>';
                                str += '</li>';
                                str += '</ul>';
                                str += '<hr>';
                            });
                        }
                        str +='</div>';
                        $('#list-contact').html(str);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
                        // alert('Local error callback');
                    }
                });
            }
            function show_name(ship_reg_num){

            }
</script>
```

Comment: Sounds like the server may not be sending JSON back? What's the response from the server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your $.each function is wrong.. use forEach to build ui str.

Comment: forEach is not defined

Comment: forEach is a array method so use like this res.data.forEach((data,index)=>{})

Comment: And `$.each` is a jQuery method. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ . You don't know what the value of `res.data` is, so why do you assume that it is an array?